# Best way to converting .Net4/MVC 2.0 to .net4.0/MVC 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

So i have given an old project from my manager to upgrade it to new version on .net and MVC. So i checked the project file and refrerence of my system.web.mvc and found that the project is in .Net 4 and MVC 2.0. Now we need to upgrade it to .net4 MVC 4.5. I looked at bunch of documents but kind of skeptic which to follow and whats the best practice.

Can anyone tell me whats the best way to do it seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no clear cut way to go about this. My suggestion is to look at the differences between the versions, figure out what new functionality you're not leveraging and start refactoring to implement it. I would also look to see if any of the patterns had changed but it's going to be up to your specific needs.